# Metaprogramming - check if all types are true

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming

I'm trying to implement in **C++11** a functionality to check if all non-template boolean parameters are true. To give you some example

```
static_assert(all_true<true, true, true>::value) // should pass
static_assert(all_true<true, false, true>::value) // should fail
```

Here you have my working attempt

```
template <bool b>
struct bool_type : std::false_type {};

template <>
struct bool_type<true> : std::true_type {};

template <bool val, bool... vals>
struct all_true : bool_type<bool_type<val>::value && all_true<vals...>::value> {};

template <>
struct all_true<true> : bool_type<true> {};

template <>
struct all_true<false> : bool_type<false> {};
```

As you can see, it requires additional struct **bool_type** (with specializations) and **are_true** (with specializations too). Do you see any way to simplify my code? Thanks in advance for your responses.

**EDIT**
As @user17732522 noticed that can be done with `std::integral_constant` so now the implementation looks like this

```
template <bool val, bool... vals>
struct all_true : std::integral_constant<bool, val && all_true<vals...>::value> {};

template <>
struct all_true<true> : std::integral_constant<bool, true> {};

template <>
struct all_true<false> : std::integral_constant<bool, false> {};
```

Comment: Actually C++11 or something newer? Because `static_assert(all_true<true, true, true>::value)` is not valid C++11 syntax and all of it is much simpler in C++17 and later.

Comment: `bool_type<val>::value` is exactly the same as `val` and `bool_type<val>` is the same as `std::integral_constant<bool, val>`.

Comment: You might want to look at [std::conjunction_v](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction)

Comment: @user17732522 ach, of course, you're right, that could be
`struct all_true : std::integral_constant<bool, val && all_true<vals...>::value> {};`

Comment: I would want `all_true<>::value` (zero template arguments) to be valid and true. (True is the natural answer from a mathematical view, and is the behavior of the runtime `std::all_of` and C++17's metaprogramming `std::conjunction` and an empty C++17 `&&` fold expression.)

Comment: @aschepler fair point

Answer (score 3):

> Do you see any way to simplify my code?

##### C+17 Version

With C++17 there is a much simpler way using [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) with C++17 as shown below.

```
template<bool... vals>
struct all_true
{
    constexpr static bool value = (vals &&...); 
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/azK6fE9GP)

---

##### C+11 Version

```
//declaration for most generic version
template <bool...>
struct all_true;

//single argument version
template <bool val>
struct all_true<val>
{
    static constexpr bool value = val;
};
//for two or more
template <bool val, bool... vals>
struct all_true<val, vals...>
{
    static constexpr bool value = val && all_true<vals...>::value;
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d517YcWh6)

Comment: Yep, but I have to use Cpp11 standard

Comment: @NiklasMan I see. This can still help future readers so I'm gonna leave it here and maybe add c++11 solution also.

Comment: Sure, thanks for your help

Comment: @NiklasMan I've added the C++11 version also. Check out the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

A trick can be done in C++11 to avoid recursion:

```
// Helper to "group" all boolean value
// "Similar" to std::bool_constant (C++17), but for several value
template <bool...> struct bool_constants{};

template <bool... vals>
using all_true = std::is_same<bool_constants<true, vals...>,
                              bool_constants<vals..., true>>;
```

`{ x1, x2, ..xn, true} == {true, x1, x2, .., xn}` only when

- `x1 == true`
- `x2 == x1`
- `x[i] == x[i-1]`
- `xn == true`

In C++17, fold expression allows to have simply:

```
template <bool... vals>
using all_true = std::bool_constant<(vals && ...)>;
```

Comment: Did you reply first? I shoud delete, if that's the case.

Comment: You might hover mouse on "anwsered .. ago" to have more precise time: 16h34:51Z for you, 16h24:22Z for me. No problem to keep your answer though ;-)

Comment: 1+ for good answer, anyway. Looks like an internet sync issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a none-recursive strict C++11 implementation:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<bool...>
struct bool_list{};

template<bool... args>
stuct all_true:
    std::is_same< bool_list<true, args...>
                , bool_list<args..., true>
    > // is_same
{}; // all_true
```

The basis of this implementation is a digital design theorem:

**a sequence of bits consists of all equal values, if and only if any none-zero rotation of the sequence is identical to original.**

In this sample a 1 bit rotation is created through insertion of `true` at the begining and ending of the sequence. If `false` were used instead, we'd be implmenting `all_false` or `none_true`.

If C++14 were available, `std::integral_sequence<bool,args...>` would be used, instead of declaring `bool_list`.

I guess this is the shortest cleanest and fastest achievable through C++11.
Trait inheritance (`: std::is_same`) used to be a common practice back then, but template aliasing can also be used:

```
using all_true = std::is_same</*like the above*/>;
```